# Usage of Mapping annotation with "this" value (@Mapping("this")) on a field while using github's dozermapper

Tags: java, testng, dozer

I came to see a class in which `@Mapping("this")` was added to a field and a test method which checked that the source object and resulting object are not equal after invoking the map method in github's dozermapper.

As I cannot post the actual code, I am adding a similar class and test method below. (I have used lombok's `@Data`, `@NoArgsConstructor` and `@AllArgsConstructor` annotations to avoid explicitly specifying the getter, setter and constructors.)

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TestObj
{
   private int id;

   @Mapping("this")
   private String name;

}
```

Test method :

```
@Test
public void testMapper() {
   TestObj testObj = new TestObj(1, "test");
   TestObj testCopy = DozerBeanMapperBuilder.create().build().map(testObj, TestObj.class);
   Assert.assertNotEquals(testObj, testCopy);
}
```

The test was passed. If I remove `@Mapping("this")`, then the same test would fail. So how has the @Mapping("this") changed the mapping procedure so that the mapped object and source object are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Mapping` annotation is used when the field names in the source and destination class differ.

For example, The below code would map the `fullName` field in the source class object to the `name` field in the destination class object. This is particularly useful when you are mapping objects of two different classes.

```
@Mapping("fullName")
private int name;
```

So if we use `@Mapping("this")` on the `name` field, then it would map the source class itself to the `name` field. Here since the `name` is of type `String`, the `toString()` representation of the source class would be mapped to the `name` field. An exception would be thrown if we have used an incompatible type like `int` for the `name` field. The source object itself would have been stored in the `name` field, if it was of `Object` type or the same type as the source object.

So, in the given question, the source and the destination class are the same, but the `@Mapping("this")` is provided to the `name` field. So if the source object was like `TestObj(id=1,name="test")`, then the mapped object would be `TestObj(id=1,name="TestObj(id=1,name="test")"`, i.e the `name` field would be the `toString()` of the source object. Hence both the objects would not be equal.

If the `@Mapping("this")` is removed, the test would fail because, the `@Data` annotation adds an `equals()` method which checks the equality of individual fields and thus the source and mapped object would be equal.